# delete all customers with email ending with example.com with specific DATE period

Tags: mysql

**delete** all customers with email ending with `example.com` using mysql with specific DATE period from `9/15/2018 to 9/28/2018`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
delete customers
where email like '%example.com'
and date_created between '2018-09-15' AND '2018-09-28';
```

But first, run a select to see if it will delete the correct rows:

```
select * from customers
where email like '%example.com'
and date_created between '2018-09-15' AND '2018-09-28';
```

Comment: The `CASTing` is unnecessary.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks Rick.  I admit, it was a copy/paste from another example.